# Rails 4 Strong Parameters - Stack level too deep on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've been playing around with Rails 4 and having some issues updating a record with strong parameters. I keep getting a "Stack Level Too Deep" error. I'm trying to update a post record that has_one meta_data.

post.rb

```
  has_one :meta_data, :as => :meta_dataeable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta_data
  after_initialize do
    self.build_meta_data unless self.meta_data.present?
  end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(permitted_params)
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update_attributes(permitted_params)
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end

def permitted_params
  params.require(:post).permit(
    :title, 
    :body, 
    :excerpt, 
    :permalink, 
    :content_type, 
    :author_id, 
    :media, 
    :commenting, 
    :published_at, 
    :public, 
    {:meta_data_attributes => [:title, :description, :keywords, :menu_name]}
  )    
end
```

Creating a new record works without any problems and saves the associated meta_data record. Updating gives me a Stack Level Too Deep error. When I remove the `{:meta_data_attributes => [:title, :description, :keywords, :menu_name]}` from my permitted params, saving works without a problem

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem, need to add `:id` as a permitted parameter for the meta_data_attributes.